# Extrapolate “middle” file contents using Python

Tags: python, python-3.x, file

So, here's the facts:

I'm iterating over a bunch of files inside a directory.
The first thing I need doing on these files is extracting the first block of N bytes (let's call this "heading" block and let's say its 16 bytes long, just to say a number, that's not the point here) and compare it with a "reference" block of bytes of the same size to see if they're equal. If that's not the case ('cause the blocks contents differ or the file is even smaller than the reference-block size), I'll skip the file and go on with next one; in case the blocks equals then I found a "candidate" file.
In my case, a "good candidate" file is one that also has a "tail" block, let's have it the same size as the heading one to simplify things, and also let's say I can be sure that if a "candidate" file in that directory is "big enough" (= bigger than head+tail blocks size) the file is "good" to be processed (= no need to compare its "tail" block) so now I need to *extrapolate its "middle" content* (= the data found after the heading block and before the tail block) to do some further stuffs with it ... and here comes the question: suppose I already did the head/reference block comparison and I just found a "candidate", **how can I read/get the contents in the "middle" of the file now?** (when the file is "big enough", of course)

(Real things are a little more complicated than that, in the way that the "bad candidates" in the first directory loop should be moved to a different directory to be iterated over again with a smaller reference block... but that's definitely not the point here.)

**I need using only python (>= 3) to do all this.**

I searched here on StackOverflow but seems something like this hasn't been asked/replied already before.

P.S.
I'm posting an answer to this myself as I found a way to do it and hope others might find it useful as a starting point idea maybe. Yet I'd really appreciate to see more if possible, I'm always happy to see different/better approach to achieve the needs or any comments you'd like to share of course, thanks

Comment: It feels so bad... This is the second time I "try" to add this. The first time I focused on the main point only wanting to avoid specific scenario details 'cause I thought it could lead to loose the focus on the much simpler point in the question. Now I expanded it a lot providing more details on the scenario to make it clear (yet trying to keep the focus on the main point of the question and not on all the side stuffs), yet seems like I only got closing votes for "needs details or clarity"... And no comments to understand what's so "unclear" about it... Please, help me understand

Comment: P.S. more similarly to the first version of the question the point is simply like: using python (>=3) how to get the contents of a file from 16 bytes after its beginning to 16 bytes before the end of it?

Comment: Your question and answer would probably be much more useful and appreciated if the question were clearer and easier to understand. Can you rewrite it (and the title)? "Extrapolate" is really misleading. Basically, it seems that your question boils down to "How do I read the start, then the end, then the rest of a file?"

Answer (score -1):

So far this is a very simple python3 script you could use to do that:

```
block = 16  # this is the block size (using same size for "head" and "tail" in this example)
f = open("path/to/file", "rb")
# ...
# ... (code for head/reference block comparison will be here)
# ...
try:
    # if I get this far I found a "candidate" file
    f.seek(-block,2)  # put offset right before "tail" block
    p = f.tell() - block  # p is storing "middle" contents size
except OSError:
    p = -1  # something went wrong while calculating "middle" contents size

if p <= 0:  # (= the candidate file was a "bad" one)
    print("either file size is too small or block size is too big")
else: # (= the candidate file is a "good" one, let's process it now)
    f.seek(block)  # put offset right after "head" block
    middle = f.read(p)  # finally retrieved "middle" file contents
    print(middle)  # (process data as needed instead here)
```

Comment: Getting a down-vote on the answer makes me feel even worse now... I really can't understand: I tried the code and it works as expected retrieving the contents I needed... So why? What's the reason to consider it "wrong" like that?